# How to make my pygame tron game draw the players?

Tags: python, pygame

My tron game that I am trying to make won't run the actual characters. I've created a class for both player one and player two, and in the while loop I have put a the draw command, but it still is not running the game. Any tips or solutions? Sorry for the lack of comments in the code.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

black = 0,0,0 #Create black for background
P1_Color = 0,0,225 #Create blue for player 1
P2_Color = 255,0,0 #Create red for player 2

class Player:
    def __init__(self, x, y, direction, color, position):
        self.x = x #X coord
        self.y = y #Y coord
        self.position = (x,y)
        self.direction = direction #direction
        self.color = color #color
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(100, self.y - 1, 2, 2) #player rect object
    
    def draw(self):
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(100, self.y - 1, 2, 2)  # redefines rect
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.color, self.rect, 0)  # draws player onto screen
    
    def move(self):
        self.x += self.direction[0] * 2
        self.y += self.direction[1] * 2
    
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 750))  # creates window
pygame.display.set_caption("Tron")  # sets window title
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

p1 = Player(50, 0, (2, 0), P1_Color, (500,0))  # creates p1
p2 = Player(50, 50, (-2, 0), P2_Color, (0,500)) #create p2

done = False
while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():  # gets all event in last tick
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            # === Player 1 === #
            if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                p1.direction = (0, -2)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
                p1.direction = (0, 2)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_a:
                p1.direction = (-2, 0)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_d:
                p1.direction = (2, 0)
            # === Player 2 === #
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                p2.direction = (0, -2)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                p2.direction = (0, 2)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                p2.direction = (-2, 0)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                p2.direction = (2, 0)
    screen.fill(black)
    p1.draw()
    p1.move()
    p2.draw()
    p2.move()
            
pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to update the display with either [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) or [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip):

```py
done = False
while not done:
    # [...]

    screen.fill(black)
    p1.draw()
    p1.move()
    p2.draw()
    p2.move()
    pygame.display.update()
```